# When deleting a VM added to a domain, does SCVMM remove the machine from the domain?

Tags: domain, domain-controller, scvmm

I have created several machines from a template and each one has automatically been added to my set domain. On deletion of the machines, are the machines removed from the domain or are the now orphaned machines left on the domain controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SCVMM only handles the deletion of the machine from the host, it doesn't complete any AD-Integrated actions.

Your best bet to accomplish this would be to script the deletion using powershell and the SCVMM and AD cmdlets.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I suspected as much. I do feel that is a bit of a missing piece of functionality. A colleague has informed me that a similar Citrix product will automatically remove the machine from the domain. Ah well, can't have everything!